# SharePoint Online - Detectar ítems eliminados

Tags: sharepoint, office365

¿Hay alguna manera de detectar el evento de eliminar un item en SharePoint Online, para luego disparar un WF?

Comment: Normalmente en SharePoint programas manejadores de eventos para capturar la creación, modificación o eliminación de un ítem de una lista. Fíjate este artículo en español que muestra como hacer un evento en SharePoint online. http://www.compartimoss.com/revistas/numero-15/manejadores-de-eventos-remotos

Comment: Puedes intentarlo con sharepoint designer. Creando un workflow que al eliminar un item ejecute el workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como lo indica @jpussacq, debes crear un proyecto de tipo sandbox para manejar esos eventos, recuerda seleccionar el evento `ItemDeleting` el cual es el evento que captura antes de que se haya eliminado el item de SharePoint. El evento `ItemDelete` es cuando ya se eliminó el item.